# ToJSON with custom representation

Tags: json, haskell

I have some type like

```
data D = D { x :: Maybe X }
```

and I need to serialize it to JSON like: `{"x": {XXX} }`, where `XXX` is the representation of `X` when `x` is **Just X** object. OK, BUT when it's **Nothing** it must be `{}`, i.e.:  `{"x": {}}`. How to implement `ToJSON` instance for such `D` ?  Conversion to `String` is wrong, I get `"{}"` instead of `{}`

Comment: Hm, seems that I found how to do it, so question is now, is it right: `maybe AT.emptyObject toJSON (x myObj)` where `AT` is `Data.Aeson.Types`  ?

Comment: There are some possible options but I don't see the one you want: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:defaultOptions If you found an answer please post it.

Comment: @Paul-AG: If you found the answer, then it can be useful to answer your own question, such that users that later have the same problem, can find your answer.

Comment: I think there may be some possible ambiguity around what you mean by `"{XXX}"`. What if `X ~ Int`? Should you have `{"x":{7}}`? That would be a malformed JSON... That said, the answer I would've recommended is the one you suggest in your comment. Feel free to post it!

Comment: @Alec: the way I understood it, was that `X` is another object with `ToJSON` support, so then it can recursively be encoded.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Of course - but that representation may not be with curly braces (as is the case for `X ~ Int`), hence the ambiguity around `"{XXX}"`.

Comment: what I can add here, is: yes, it's possible a malformed JSON, but such JSON (or what?) wants Crucible REST API in one of its calls. I tried to use `null` instead of `{}` but it fails with 500 in this case. Even more, empty `{}` is in their documentation. Strange, yes... But when I implemented this `{}` - it works, and this is like in documentation

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not misunderstanding, I think you want this:

```
instance ToJSON D where
    toJSON (D maybeX) =
      object ["x" .= (case maybeX of
                        Nothing -> mempty
                        Just x -> toJSON x)]
```

And, as you pointed out in the comments, you can golf that inner expression as `maybe (Object mempty) toJSON maybeX :: Value`.

Comment: `maybe (Object mempty) toJSON maybeX` is the same as `maybe mempty toJSON maybeX` which is the same as `foldMap toJSON maybeX`

Comment: actually i don't think there's a Monoid Value instance?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I forgot about types, just performed quick syntactic transformation. My version with `foldMap` doesn't work :(